# is saving jwt in vuex state a security issue?

Tags: security, vue.js, jwt

In short, Here is the screenshot of my server rendered application: In **fourth last** line of the view-source in the given image, you can see the token. This is because I have to save it in the vuex state.

So Is it a best practice?  Is it even secure? What if a user opens a malicious site whose owner has put an iframe or something to call my this website in his own page and copy the jwt from here. then he can have the admin access to my application? dont know if this is possible with iframe but does anyone know of any other mechanism?

What do you suggest?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just a JS variable in memory.

If another frame can access this variable, then that frame can also call any methods or buttons on your page. So, instead of stealing your token, they could even call "withdraw()" method or click on submit button.

So, the point is that if a logged-in session of your app is available in an iframe inside another page, it's anyway terrible regardless of Vue or Vuex.

Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) restriction is there to prevent this. So that scenario will only be possible if you specifically set your server settings as less secure.

That said, if you keep it in cookies, and avoid it in variables it can be better. But, then you have to look at the other problems with cookies.

Update:

1. Chrome has many security checks for preventing other URLs (other domains) from loading your page into an IFrame. Only a similar domain will be allowed to load your page into an IFrame. So, it's difficult for another page to load your page in an IFrame and then access your JS variables. It's possible only if you keep your server settings in low-security mode. If your server CORS settings are ok, then you are fine.
2. Server-side rendered content is also not a problem as long as you are using HTTPS. That's because HTTPS keeps content confidential. So, only the server and intended recipient can see the content in transit (the whole thing which you have shown in the screenshot).

Update #2:

- Keeping JWT in Vuex will keep it alive only until the page is refreshed, so each time user would have to login.
- The alternative for Vuex is setting JWT as a cookie with short expiry in HTTP response (with HttpOnly, it will make cookie inaccessible to JS).
- Also, if you want it to stay on the computer for a week or a month (like the usual 'Remember me on this PC' option) saving the JWT as a cookie, or in localStorage can work.
- Cookies are also reasonably secure... they will be sent along with the request automatically but only to the same domain and you can set a flag to force the browser to send this cookie only with HTTPS connections. Watch out for CSRF though.
- Local storage is also fairly secure. Data saved by a script is also available only to scripts loaded from the same domain. Watch out for XSS which is what we already mentioned for Vuex. Also, it doesn't expire automatically.

Some more information on this topic:

1. https://stormpath.com/blog/where-to-store-your-jwts-cookies-vs-html5-web-storage
2. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=13QPmRuhbhU&list=PLAO1W_Ggxtx305USJbELM6vZOeF8aNsLq&index=34&t=0s
3. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c6mqdsfWdmE&list=PLAO1W_Ggxtx305USJbELM6vZOeF8aNsLq&index=32&t=0s

Comment: I was looking for some cases in which this token can be exploited, and If it is reallly critical I shall avoid it altogether. My original question is whether this token or any state variable can be exploited? is it a security issue? especially in a server rendered application.

Comment: @RameshPareek I added a bit of update to the answer.

Comment: ok. that addresses the question. however I shall appreciate if you could add a few lines to answer the second part of the question " Is there any other mechanism ...?"